# Algebraic functions - $\sin{x}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I would like to know an appropriate response to this question:

An algebraic function is defined as a function which solves a polynomial equation $p(x,f(x))=0$.
Show that the function

$f(x) = \sin{x}$

is not algebraic.

This is my response:

We can observe that $p(x,0)=0$ must have finitely many solutions, unless it is identically $0$, neither of which cases includes $\sin(x)$.

is it good?

Comment: Yes, exactly the correct argument!

Comment: I'd say that's reasonable.

Comment: @AndresMejia: no non-constant periodic function can be algebraic (or even semi-algebraic, which means that its graph can be defined by a finite set of polynomial equalities and inequalities)